# Braintree data-collector:3.15.0 non compliant on play store

Tags: android, android-studio, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data

My [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYrhr.png) app rejected with this issue.

We are using data-collecter version is `3.15.0`
by using this we are getting device data using this function

```
override fun getDeviceData(activity: AppCompatActivity, config: String): Result<String> {
        val braintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(activity, config)
        val deviceDataBox = ArrayBlockingQueue<Result<String>>(1)
        DataCollector.collectDeviceData(braintreeFragment) { deviceData ->
            print(deviceData)
            deviceDataBox.put(Result.Valid(deviceData))
        }
        return deviceDataBox.take()
    }
```

But, After upgrading data-collecter version - `4.31.0`

throwing error in this lines - error: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

```
DataCollector.collectDeviceData(braintreeFragment) { deviceData ->
            print(deviceData)
            deviceDataBox.put(Result.Valid(deviceData))
}
```

app also not building giving error like this.

```
Execution failed for task ':checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.braintreepayments.api.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-braintree-3.17.4-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.4) and jetified-braintree-core-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree-core:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class com.braintreepayments.api.CrashReporter found in modules jetified-braintree-3.17.4-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.4) and jetified-braintree-core-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree-core:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class com.braintreepayments.api.DataCollector found in modules jetified-braintree-3.17.4-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.4) and jetified-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class com.braintreepayments.api.DataCollector$1 found in modules jetified-braintree-3.17.4-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.4) and jetified-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class com.braintreepayments.api.Json found in modules jetified-core-3.17.4-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:core:3.17.4) and jetified-shared-utils-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:shared-utils:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class com.braintreepayments.api.PaymentMethod found in modules jetified-braintree-3.17.4-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.4) and jetified-braintree-core-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:braintree-core:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.Environment found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.InvalidInputException found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.MagnesResult found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.MagnesSDK found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.MagnesSettings found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.MagnesSettings$Builder found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.MagnesSource found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$b$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$b$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d$c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d$d found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d$e found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$d$f found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$e found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$e$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$e$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$e$c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$f found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$f$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$g found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$h found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$h$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$h$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$h$c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$h$d found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$i found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$j found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$k found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$k$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$k$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$l found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$m found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.c$n found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.d found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.e found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.f found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.g found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.g$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.g$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.g$c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.g$d found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.g$e found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.h found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.h$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.h$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.i found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.j found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.k found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.k$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.k$b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.l found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.l$a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.m found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.MagnesNetworking found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.MagnesNetworkingFactory found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.MagnesNetworkingFactoryImpl found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.PayPalCertificate found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.a found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.b found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.c found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.d found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.e found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
     Duplicate class lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.base.f found in modules jetified-data-collector-3.17.4-runtime (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:3.17.4) and jetified-paypal-data-collector-4.31.0-runtime (com.braintreepayments.api:paypal-data-collector:4.31.0)
```

How we resolve this?

we need to get device data on this.

Comment: Looks like you have another dependency that uses an earlier version of braintree data collector, possibly `com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.4`. Update it to the latest as well. Otherwise you need to exclude the data collector library from that dependency but things might break further.

Comment: I already texted that. It's not working